# Remove all html tags from a string keeping only one of them. Advanced strip_tags with one identifier attribute

Tags: php, html, replace, preg-replace, strip-tags

I need to remove HTML tags in one string and keep only one type of them. I have one string that contains this:

```
 <!-- comment -->   <div id="55"> text </div> <span name=annotation value=125> 2 text </span> <p id="55"> text 3</p><span>text 4 <span>
```

and I need this:

```
text  <span name=annotation value=125> 2 text </span> text 3text4
```

so I need to delete all the HTML tags except those that have this form

```
"/(<span[^>]*annotation[^>]*value=.?(\w*).?[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/span>/"
```

I use this as part of another expression but to get an idea

How can I do this?

I know it can be done with `preg_replace()`, but I do not know what is the pattern I need.

An example:

```
$str='<!-- comment --><p><b>Deoxyribonucleic acid</b> (<b>DNA</b>) is 
   a molecule encoding the <a href="/wiki/Genetics" title="Genetics">genetic</a> instructions
   used in the development and functioning of all known living <a href="/wiki/Organism" title="Organism">organi
   sms</a> and many <a href="/wiki/Virus" title="Virus">viruses</a>. Along with <a href="/wiki/RNA" title="RNA">RNA</a> and <a href="/wiki/Proteins" title="Proteins" class="mw-redirect">proteins</a>, DNA is one of the three major 
   <a href="/wiki/Macromolecules" title="Macromolecules" class="mw-redirect">macromolecules</a> 
   that are essential for all known forms of <a href="/wiki/Life" title="Life">life</a>.
   Genetic information is encoded<span id="200120131815150" 
   class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation"> as a sequence of nucleotides (</span><a href="/wiki/Guanine" title="Guanine"><span id="200120131815151" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">
   guanine</span></a><span id="200120131815152" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">, </span><a href="/wiki/Adenine" title="Adenine"><span id="200120131815153" class="mymetastasis" value="247"
   name="annotation">adenine</span></a><span id="200120131815154" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">,
   </span><a href="/wiki/Thymine" title="Thymine"><span id="200120131815155" class="mymetastasis" value="247"
   name="annotation">thymine</span></a><span id="200120131815156" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">, 
   and </span><a href="/wiki/Cytosine" title="Cytosine">
   <span id="200120131815157" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">cytosine</span></a><span id="200120131815158" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">) 
   recorded using the letters G, A, T, and C. Most DNA molecules are double-strande</span>d helices, consisting of two long <a href="/wiki/Polymers" title="Polymers" class="mw-redirect">polymers</a> of simple units called <a href="/wiki/Nucleotide" 
   title="Nucleotide">nucleotides</a>, molecules with <a href="/wiki/Backbone_chain" title="Backbone chain">backbones</a>
   made of alternating <a href="/wiki/Monosaccharide" title="Monosaccharide">sugars<
   /a> (<a href="/wiki/Deoxyribose" title="Deoxyribose">deoxyribose</a>) and <a href="/wiki/Phosphate"
   title="Phosphate">phosphate</a> groups (related to phosphoric acid), with the <a href="/wiki/Nucleobases" title="Nucleobases" class="mw-redirect">nucleobases</a> (G, A, T, C) attached to the sugars. DNA is well-suited for biological information storage, since the DNA backbone is resistant to cleavage and the double-stranded structure provides the molecule with a 
   built-in duplicate of the encoded information.</p>';
```

PD:line breaks,tabs,etc are unintentional. Part of the source text.

Comment: Do not use regex to parse HTML. Use some XML parser.

Comment: I just quickly glanced at your question so I don't know if this will help. http://psoug.org/snippet/Convert-HTML-to-plain-text_36.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need multiple `regex` to do this.

Working code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

    $str = '<!-- comment -->   <div id="55"> text </div> <span name=annotation value=125> 2 text </span> <p id="55"> text 3</p><span>text 4 </span>';

    // Save needed values
    $str = preg_replace("/<(span[^>]*?annotation.*?)>(.*?)<\/(.*?)>/", "!!!$1!!!$2!!!$3!!!", $str); 

    // Remove everything else
    $re = "/(<[^>]*?>)/";
    $str = preg_replace($re, "", $str);

    // Restore
    $str = preg_replace("/\!\!\!(span[^>]*?annotation.*?)\!\!\!(.*?)\!\!\!(.*?)\!\!\!/", "<$1>$2</$3>", $str); 

    echo $str;
?>
```

Output:

```
text  <span name=annotation value=125> 2 text </span>  text 3text 4
```

---

Input:

```
$str='<!-- comment --><p><b>Deoxyribonucleic acid</b> (<b>DNA</b>) is 
   a molecule encoding the <a href="/wiki/Genetics" title="Genetics">genetic</a> instructions
   used in the development and functioning of all known living <a href="/wiki/Organism" title="Organism">organi
   sms</a> and many <a href="/wiki/Virus" title="Virus">viruses</a>. Along with <a href="/wiki/RNA" title="RNA">RNA</a> and <a href="/wiki/Proteins" title="Proteins" class="mw-redirect">proteins</a>, DNA is one of the three major 
   <a href="/wiki/Macromolecules" title="Macromolecules" class="mw-redirect">macromolecules</a> 
   that are essential for all known forms of <a href="/wiki/Life" title="Life">life</a>.
   Genetic information is encoded<span id="200120131815150" 
   class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation"> as a sequence of nucleotides (</span><a href="/wiki/Guanine" title="Guanine"><span id="200120131815151" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">
   guanine</span></a><span id="200120131815152" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">, </span><a href="/wiki/Adenine" title="Adenine"><span id="200120131815153" class="mymetastasis" value="247"
   name="annotation">adenine</span></a><span id="200120131815154" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">,
   </span><a href="/wiki/Thymine" title="Thymine"><span id="200120131815155" class="mymetastasis" value="247"
   name="annotation">thymine</span></a><span id="200120131815156" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">, 
   and </span><a href="/wiki/Cytosine" title="Cytosine">
   <span id="200120131815157" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">cytosine</span></a><span id="200120131815158" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">) 
   recorded using the letters G, A, T, and C. Most DNA molecules are double-strande</span>d helices, consisting of two long <a href="/wiki/Polymers" title="Polymers" class="mw-redirect">polymers</a> of simple units called <a href="/wiki/Nucleotide" 
   title="Nucleotide">nucleotides</a>, molecules with <a href="/wiki/Backbone_chain" title="Backbone chain">backbones</a>
   made of alternating <a href="/wiki/Monosaccharide" title="Monosaccharide">sugars<
   /a> (<a href="/wiki/Deoxyribose" title="Deoxyribose">deoxyribose</a>) and <a href="/wiki/Phosphate"
   title="Phosphate">phosphate</a> groups (related to phosphoric acid), with the <a href="/wiki/Nucleobases" title="Nucleobases" class="mw-redirect">nucleobases</a> (G, A, T, C) attached to the sugars. DNA is well-suited for biological information storage, since the DNA backbone is resistant to cleavage and the double-stranded structure provides the molecule with a 
   built-in duplicate of the encoded information.</p>';
```

Output:

```
Deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA) is 
   a molecule encoding the genetic instructions
   used in the development and functioning of all known living organi
   sms and many viruses. Along with RNA and proteins, DNA is one of the three major 
   macromolecules 
   that are essential for all known forms of life.
   Genetic information is encoded<span id="200120131815150" 
   class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation"> as a sequence of nucleotides (</span>
   guanine<span id="200120131815152" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">, </span><span id="200120131815153" class="mymetastasis" value="247"
   name="annotation">adenine</span>,
   <span id="200120131815155" class="mymetastasis" value="247"
   name="annotation">thymine</span>, 
   and 
   <span id="200120131815157" class="mymetastasis" value="247" name="annotation">cytosine</span>) 
   recorded using the letters G, A, T, and C. Most DNA molecules are double-stranded helices, consisting of two long polymers of simple units called nucleotides, molecules with backbones
   made of alternating sugars (deoxyribose) and phosphate groups (related to phosphoric acid), with the nucleobases (G, A, T, C) attached to the sugars. DNA is well-suited for biological information storage, since the DNA backbone is resistant to cleavage and the double-stranded structure provides the molecule with a 
   built-in duplicate of the encoded information.
```

Comment: thanks but I need it in php, I have had this error `Undefined offset: 1 ` in this line `$out .=  $sub_matches[1];`.  You know it can happen

Comment: Post the exact string you are using now. You may be missing the closing tag in the last `span` tag.

Comment: a text that can be used for example is the html content in the html tag with `id=content` of this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA, adding a  <span name=annotation> anywhere in the text, the text should come out clean unless this tag

Comment: Do you need the HTML comments?

Comment: @Martin There is no `annotation` tags in the page you are referring to. I have updated my code to remove comments. Try now.

Comment: @ATOzTOA oh yeah sorry, got a page at random to be made an idea, but of course there may be comments on the string, apologizes for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Martin The solution won't work if you have nested elements. Do you need a solution in Javascript/jquery?

Comment: @ATOzTOA I updated the question and I added one example, you can test your code here [http://writecodeonline.com/php/] . I needed it to be in php. But if it can not work in php, I find a better solution.

Comment: @Martin I have updated my answer with a fully functional code... enjoy!

Comment: @Martin Maybe you should change the title to a more generic one.

Comment: @ATOzTOA thanks I already tried it but I did not think a better one. any ideas?

Comment: This one looks ok, lets leave it there :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in function for this called [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

If you only want to keep the span tag then use the second argument.

So,

```
$cleanString = strip_tags($dirtyString, '<span>');
```

Comment: OP needs a specific `span`, not all spans.